# Send some input to a Terminal window using Java on Mac OS

Tags: java, terminal

I can get a terminal window or command prompt to open on either Mac OS or Windows.  I want to send a string to that terminal or cmd window using my java.

```
  String in = " -i " + "\"" + tfIntdta.getText() + "\"";
  String rst = " - r " + "\"" + tfRstplt.getText() + "\"";
  String out = " -o " + "\"" + tfOutdta.getText() + "\""; 
  String strip = " -s" + "\"" + tfStpdta.getText() + "\"";
  String guistring = "-n gui";
  String wd = "\"" + System.getProperty("user.dir");
  String osver = System.getProperty("os.name");
  String app = "";
    if (osver.contains("Mac")){
       app = wd + "/relap5.x\"";
    } else if (osver.contains("Windows")){
       app = "\\relap5.exe";
    } else if (osver.contains("linux")) {
       app = "/relap5.x";
    }
 String run = app + in + rst + out;
```

So the string would look something like this.
"/Users/brianallison/Documents/Java/RELAP5 GUI/issrs/relap5.x" -i "" - r "" -o ""

I want the line above to appear on the terminal or cmd window and execute.

Comment: Can't you just execute the string directly? Check `Runtime`'s javacod, you're probably interested in `Runtime.exec(String command)` or one of it's overloads. Fun fact/product placement: in Groovy, `String` has an `execute` method that runs the String as a terminal command.

Comment: I have tried this and all it does is open the terminal window.
             Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app"));
             Runtime.getRuntime().exec(run);

Comment: Skip the terminal opening - just execute the string, you don't have to explicitly open the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Put your command and parameters in an array:

```
String[] command = {
    "/Users/brianallison/Documents/Java/RELAP5 GUI/issrs/relap5.x",
    "-i", "Choose your input file",
    "-r", "",
    "-o", ""
};
```

Then execute using [`Runtime#exec(String[] cmdarray)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

This answer has been put together after reading your other two questions from today, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128246/i-am-getting-string-errors) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132297/how-to-tell-java-to-ignore-spaces).

Comment: Ok so I did the above reference and It gives no error, but my program does no open up.  If I double click on my .x program it will open up, without using my Java GUI.  This is all it shows in the output window of Netbeans.   /Users/brianallison/Documents/Java/RELAP5 GUI/issrs/dist/relap5.x -i "/Users/brianallison/issrs/rs34bil.exe.04.30.2014/run/boiloff.i" -r "/Users/brianallison/issrs/rs34bil.exe.04.30.2014/run/boiloff.r" -o "/Users/brianallison/issrs/rs34bil.exe.04.30.2014/run/boiloff.o"

Comment: My .x  file opens a terminal window.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with MacOS. Perhaps someone else can answer your questions.

Comment: Anyone know about mac and Java?

Comment: Ask a new question and you will reach the whole community. It's likely only I who will notice your comment.