# I am getting string errors

Tags: java, string

After changing my string from this:

```
String osver = System.getProperty("os.name");
  if (osver.contains("Mac")){
     String app = wd + "/relap5.x\"";
    } else if (osver.contains("Windows")){
     String app = "relap5.exe";
    } else if (osver.contains("linux")) {
     String app = "/relap5.x";
    }
```

To this:

```
String[] osver = {System.getProperty("os.name")};
  if (osver.contains("Mac")){
     String[] app = {wd + "/relap5.x\""};
    } else if (osver.contains("Windows")){
     String[] app = {"relap5.exe"};
    } else if (osver.contains("linux")) {
     String[] app = {"/relap5.x"};
    }
```

I am getting errors.

```
Cannot find symbol
symbol: method contains(String)
Location variable osver of type string[]
```

Comment: Use a `List<String>` instead of `String[]`.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Do you want to check for equality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `Array` does not contain method `contains`. Do you mean the following:

```
    String osver = System.getProperty("os.name");
    String app;
    if (osver.equals("Mac")){
        app = "wd" + "/relap5.x\"";
    } else if (osver.equals("Windows")){
        app = "relap5.exe";
    } else if (osver.equals("linux")) {
        app = "/relap5.x";
    }
    System.out.println(app);
```

The above code will check for equality but if you want to check for containment then use:

```
        String osver = System.getProperty("os.name");
        String app;
        if (osver.contains("Mac")){
            app = "wd" + "/relap5.x\"";
        } else if (osver.contains("Windows")){
            app = "relap5.exe";
        } else if (osver.contains("linux")) {
            app = "/relap5.x";
        }
        System.out.println(app);
```

Comment: So what is the difference between String ()  and String[] {}?

Comment: `String` is a single string. `String[]`is an array of strings. An array can be initialized by using `{}`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do contains over an array.
You could alternatively do this:

```
List<String> osver = Arrays.asList(System.getProperty("os.name"));

    if (osver.contains("Mac")) {
        String[] app = { wd + "/relap5.x\"" };
    } else if (osver.contains("Windows")) {
        String[] app = { "relap5.exe" };
    } else if (osver.contains("linux")) {
        String[] app = { "/relap5.x" };
    }
```