# How to tell java to ignore spaces

Tags: java, spaces

I have a string that I am trying to execute.  The string contains a path to a `MacOS` `.x` file, which has a space in the path name.  When I run it Java is telling me that it cannot run the program.

```
"/Users/brianallison/Documents/Java/RELAP5 GUI/issrs/dist/relap5.x" -i "Choose your input file" -r "" -o ""
```

> May 08, 2015 2:19:37 PM my.issrs.issrsUI btnRunRelapActionPerformed
>   SEVERE: null java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/Users/brianallison/Documents/Java/RELAP5": error=2, No such file or
>   directory

I have tried putting quotes around the path, but Java is ignoring the quotes.  As you can see on the first line that is how it supposed to go, but Java is cutting it off at `RELAP5`.

Comment: If this is the command line parameters to your program, where's the code that handles it?

Comment: As a workaround, you could rename your directory to avoid spaces.

Comment: show us the java code please

Comment: Have you tried using [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)?

Comment: Never use `Runtime.exec(String)`. It was ill-conceived and fragile by design, and that's why you're getting this failure. You should always use `Runtime.exec(String[])` or `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: @Brian Allison: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125967/send-some-input-to-a-terminal-window-using-java-on-mac-os/30132595#30132595) to your other question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape space with back slash:

```
"/Users/brianallison/Documents/Java/RELAP5\ GUI/issrs/dist/relap5.x" -i "Choose your input file" -r "" -o ""
```